# MVC ~/ not resolving to application root in virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have multiple websites hosted on the same server with structure as follows:

http://primary-domain.com/hostedsites/MVCWebApplication1/ = http://MVCWebApplication1.com/

http://primary-domain.com/hostedsites/MVCWebApplication2/ = http://MVCWebApplication2.com/

...

The problem is, all `~/` references made in a hosted site (i.e. MVCWebApplication1, MVCWebApplication2, etc) resolve to

http://MVCWebApplication1.com/hostedsites/MVCWebApplication1/

and not

http://MVCWebApplication1.com

Please note:

I already have the following my web.config:

```
<rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
  <match url=".*" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was using a bunch of work arounds:

In `web.config`:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And instead of creating links like this:

```
<a href="~/Help">Help</a>
```

doing this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Help") // This seems to create clean urls
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert your virtual directories to applications in IIS.

Comment: They are currently all set as 'Application root', I'm in a shared environment so have limited control over IIS.